# What can go wrong with admin url?

Tags: python, django

I am new in Python, I have a problem with the admin URL.
When I type

```
localhost:8000/admin/
```

My browser tells me:

```
DoesNotExist at /admin/
Question matching query does not exist
```

My index page and detail pages work fine.
I thought it was a mistake in the order of URL's,
I changed the order of the admin and detail URL,
but still nothing.

Can somebody please give me a hint.

project/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include,  url
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', 'books.views.index', name='index'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^(?P<book_title>[\w_-]+)/$', 'books.views.detail', name='detail'),
]                   

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

books/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Question


def index(request):
   latest_question_list = Question.objects.all
   context = {'latest_question_list': latest_question_list}
   return render(request, 'books/index.html', context)

def detail(request, book_title):
   question = Question.objects.get(title=book_title)
   return render(request, 'books/detail.html', {'question': question})
```

Comment: Have you added ```'django.contrib.admin'``` to ```INSTALLED_APPS``` into settings.py?..

Comment: `Question matching query does not exist` → this error means that somewhere you are using `Question.objects.get(...)` and that call is failing.

Comment: Please post the full traceback. This will help us understand what's going on.

Comment: I have added 'django.contrib.admin' to INSTALLED_APPS.

Comment: Perhaps ```latest_question_list = Question.objects.all()``` instead of ```latest_question_list = Question.objects.all```? You missed the call.

Comment: But please enable ```DEBUG = True``` and show full traceback!
It looks like matched 'urlconf' is not one expected (it isn't ```admin``` app). To check this out enable debug and show the output of localhost:8000/admin/ It will show matched URL patterns.

Comment: Thanks Vladimir I forgot to put parentheses for Question.objects.all       So silly of me.

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to put parentheses for Question.objects.all So silly of me.

Answer (score 0):

add this before urlpatterns in urls.py

```
admin.autodiscover()
```

Comment: Since 1.7, [`autodiscover()` is no longer needed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.autodiscover).